# Meteor minimongoid update()

Tags: meteor

So I have already written a fairly large app in meteor but just adding minimongoid package to it.  I have figured out it likes first() rather than findOne(), create() rather than insert(), but I can't figure out how to update a document.  I am trying to do the following, but it shows the error below...  What am I doing wrong?

```
Transactions.update {_id: txn._id},
        $set:
            "isActive": false



TypeError: Object function Transactions() {
I20140302-18:22:54.226(-5)?     return Transactions.__super__.constructor.apply(this,     arguments);
I20140302-18:22:54.226(-5)?   } has no method 'update'
```

All I have in my postings.coffee is

```
class @Transactions extends Minimongoid
  @_collection: new Meteor.Collection('transactions')
```

Comment: wow, so much stuff here: coffeescript, minimongoid, etc. The error says there is no method called "updated" on your class. Are you sure you want to subclass from minimongoid?

Answer (score 0):

With minimongoid you update object instances rather then with Class methods.

Something like this:

```
aTransaction = Transaction.create({-some attributes-})
aTransaction.update({attributeName: attributeValue})
```

Answer (score 0):

I am still new to MeteorJS but let me try. This took a while before I figured out on my own. Good thing we use RoR at work. What I am going to do is something like:

on server JavaScript: (If you use Rails, this should be easy to get.)

```
Meteor.methods
  updateTransaction: (id, name, url) ->
    Transaction.find(id).update(
      "isActive": status
  )
```

then on my client JavaScript (template):

```
Template.transaction_template.events
  'submit .transaction-form': (event, template)->
    event.preventDefault() // if using an <a>, remove is using button with type=button

    status = template.find('[name=status]').value // find the input form with the name=status
    Meteor.call 'updateTransaction', { id: @_id, status }
```